# Load in images from file python pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a pygame project, and in my main directory I have a folder called "Sprites" for example. Is there a way using python to load all the images in that file into a list? I know how to put things in list using a for loop, I'm just not sure if there is a way to go through a folder's images and load them into a pygame sprite. I also know that if the images were all named the same with a number following them, I could concatenate a string, but what if they had completely different names?

Answer (score 0):

Use the os module to list the files of a directory; it will return a list

```
import os
fileList = os.listdir("path")
```

More details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir